# How to handle file I/O outside of main when redirecting input and output?

Tags: c++, file, io, fstream, io-redirection

A restriction of the program I am working on is that it should be invoked as: `./a.out < input.txt > output.txt`. The input of this program should be read from the first file, and the output should be written to the second.

So, this redirects standard input and output from and to these two files. I could simply, from `main()` for example, call `std::cin` and `std::cout`. However, I have a dedicated component which adapts my input from a file to an intermediate structure that I use elsewhere in my program.

In order to build this struct I could `#include <iostream>` in this component and read with `std::cin` from `input.txt`. However, I don't like the idea of including iostream here, and I am not sure how I would test this.

My issue comes from the I/O redirect, if the executable were invoked with filenames as strings, I would do something along the lines of

```
    InputAdapter inputAdapter;

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open(filename ,std::ios_base::in);

    auto structHoldingParsedInput = inputAdapter.adapt(infile);
```

How can I achieve something similar here?

Comment: *"I don't like the idea of including iostream here"* - Why? It would solve your problem instantly.

Comment: All you need is `std::istream&` parameters. I don't fully get your question maybe

Comment: Are you aware that `std::ifstream` and `std::cin` are interchangeable when passed to a function with `std::istream&` parameters? Same with `std::ofstream` and `std::cout` with `std::ostream&`.

Comment: @Galik Keeping in line with single responsibilities, I want an adaptor to take an open file and build this structure. It should not have to worry about parsing command line arguments and file I/O. Additionally, this ties an adaptor to a particular input stream, in the future what if input files come from some other source and not as arguments to an executable.

Comment: Which is why I think you should use `std::istream&` and `std::ostream&` adapter parameters and pass `std::cin` and `std::cout` to it as arguments.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you make your adapter parameters `std::istream&` and `std::ostream&` so you can pass in either the standard `std::cin`/`std::cout` or files you open yourself like `std::ifstream`.

A bit like this:

```
class InputAdapter
{
public:

    void adapt(std::istream& in)
    {
        // code to convert input to output here
        return created_object;        
    }

};

// ...

InputAdapter inputAdapter;

std::ifstream in("input_file");

auto structHoldingParsedInput = inputAdapter.adapt(in);
```

Now you are coding to *streams* rather than *files* you can use *any* stream, for example the standard input stream:

```
auto structHoldingParsedInput = inputAdapter.adapt(std::cin);
```

And, for testing you could use `std::istringstream`:

```
std::istringstream test_stream(R"(

put your test data in here

)");

auto structHoldingParsedInput = inputAdapter.adapt(test_stream);
```